# Horizontal spacing bmatrix in align environment

Tags: spacing, matrices, arrays

I have a large block matrix in my document, which violates the page margin slightly. I would like to reduce the horizontal spacing between the matrix elements of a row. Additionally, I want to align multiple equations. I tried with array and matrix but the `arraycolsep` command does not work as I expect.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
The following very large matrix could fit the text width if the spacing could be reduced slightly.
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{30}
\begin{align}
x =& 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}\\
=& 3
\end{align}
This could be done defining the arraycolsep:
\begin{align}
\setlength\arraycolsep{4pt}
x =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}\\
\end{align}
Unfortunately, as soon as I try to align multiple lines the arracolsep command stops doing what I expect.

\begin{align}
\setlength\arraycolsep{4pt}
x =& 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}\\
=& 3
\end{align}
As is the same for the array env

\begin{align}
\setlength\arraycolsep{4pt}
x =& 
  \left[\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccc}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{array}\right]\\
=& 3
\end{align}
Can anyone help out? Thanks!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit 1: I forgot to mention that I used a very short equation in the second line. However, the second line is also very long and both will not fit a single line.

Comment: `x =& ` and `=&3` should be `x&=` and `&=3`  see the bad space you have in your image for =3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd define a `varmatrix` environment where you can set both the `\arraycolsep` and the font size.

This is much more flexible, because you can decide for `\normalsize` and reduce the separation, but also to use smaller size.

The default is `\small` and `0.7\arraycolsep`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newsavebox{\varmatrixbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn {martin/varmatrix}
 {
  sep   .dim_set:N = \l_martin_varmatrix_sep_dim,
  delim .tl_set:N  = \l_martin_varmatrix_delim_tl,
  size  .tl_set:N  = \l_martin_varmatrix_size_tl,
  sep   .initial:n = 0.7\arraycolsep,
  size  .initial:n = \small,
 }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{varmatrix}{O{}}
 {
  \keys_set:nn {martin/varmatrix} { #1 }
  \begin{lrbox}{\varmatrixbox}
  % font size
  \l_martin_varmatrix_size_tl
  % separation
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{\l_martin_varmatrix_sep_dim}
  $\begin{\l_martin_varmatrix_delim_tl matrix}
 }
 {
  \end{\l_martin_varmatrix_delim_tl matrix}$
  \end{lrbox}
  \vcenter{\box\varmatrixbox}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{50}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
x &=
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{3pt}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}\\
  &=
  \begin{varmatrix}[delim=b,size=\normalsize,sep=3pt]
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{varmatrix}\\
  &=
  \begin{varmatrix}[delim=b,size=\small]
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{varmatrix}\\
  &=
  \begin{varmatrix}[delim=p,size=\footnotesize,sep=0.5\arraycolsep]
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{varmatrix}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some explanations.

- The `\keys_define:nn` part defines a key-value syntax for the options to `varmatrix`.

  1. the `sep` key sets the `\arraycolsep`
  2. the `delim` key sets the fences, use the standard letters of `amsmath`, `b`, `p`, `v`, `V` or even nothing for no fence
  3. the `size` key should receve a font size declaration
- the `varmatrix` environment typesets the matrix in a box, so we need to restart math mode after setting the size and the `\arraycolsep`
- after the box is finished, it is used inside `\vcenter` for vertical centering like usual matrices

Comment: This looks like a fantastic solution. However, there is much code in the beginning, which I do not fully understand, unfortunately. Would you mind to explain it to me?

Comment: @MartinHerrmann I added some comments

Answer (score 4):

I propose to combine playing with `\arraycolsep`  and using  a medium-sized matrix (80% of displaystyle size), as defined in  the `nccmath` package:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \AtBeginEnvironment{bmatrix}{\setlength{\arraycolsep}{4pt}}
    \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{30}

    \begin{document}
    The following very large matrix fits the text width using medsize matrices

    \begin{align}
    x &=
      \medmath{\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
      \end{bmatrix}}\\
    &= 3
    \end{align}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can insert a 4pt space between columns using the `@{}` syntax for `matrix`. Also, use `&=` not `=&` for proper spacing.

[image]

```
\begin{align}
x &= 
  \left[\begin{array}{*{24}{c@{\hspace{4pt}}}}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{array}\right]\\
&= 3
\end{align}
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution. However, can I additionally reduce the spacing between the brackets and the first/last columns?

Comment: Yes. Just add a negative space. For example: `\left[\!\begin{array}` will add a "negative thin space".